# Rendering a page only when two MongoDB database queries have completed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to render a page of 'projects' retrieved from a database. There are two types of projects concerning the user, the projects which they own, and the projects which they are a member of.

I'm using two asynchronous database queries, however they could finish at different times and I only want to render the page upon them both completing.

**Question:**
How can I delay the rendering until the database transactions are complete?

```
  var username = req.session.username;
  var memberProjects = [];
  var ownerProjects = [];
  var membersQuery = false;
  var ownerQuery = false;

  projects.find({"members.username" : username}).toArray(function(err, results)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
      var project = {
        title : results[i].title,
        id : results[i]._id
      }
      memberProjects[i] = project;
    }
    membersQuery = true;
  });

  projects.find({owner : req.session.username}).toArray(function(err, results)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
      var project = {
        title : results[i].title,
        id : results[i]._id
      }
      ownerProjects[i] = project;
    }
    ownerQuery = true;
  });

  if( membersQuery && ownerQuery )
  {        
    res.render('project', {
      ownerProjects : ownerProjects,
      memberProjects : memberProjects
    });        
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a working answer, i'm not sure whether it's correct or not. Please correct me if there is a better approach. I'm calling a function at the end of each database transaction:

```
  var username = req.session.username;
  var memberProjects = [];
  var ownerProjects = [];
  var membersQuery = false;
  var ownerQuery = false;

  projects.find({"members.username" : username}).toArray(function(err, results)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
      var project = {
        title : results[i].title,
        id : results[i]._id
      }
      memberProjects[i] = project;
    }
    membersQuery = true;
    render();
  });

  projects.find({owner : req.session.username}).toArray(function(err, results)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
      var project = {
        title : results[i].title,
        id : results[i]._id
      }
      ownerProjects[i] = project;
    }
    ownerQuery = true;
    render();
  });

  function render(){
    if( membersQuery && ownerQuery )
    {        
      res.render('project', {
        ownerProjects : ownerProjects,
        memberProjects : memberProjects
      });        
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While your solution works for this particular example, you should use some control flow libraries like [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) or [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Here's how I would do this with Step:

```
var Step = require('step'),
    username = req.session.username,
    memberProjects = [],
    ownerProjects = [],
    membersQuery = false,
    ownerQuery = false;

Step(
  function getData() {
    var that = this;
    projects.find({"members.username" : username}).toArray(function(err, results) {
      if (err) { throw new Error('database problem'); }
      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var project = {
          title : results[i].title,
          id : results[i]._id
        }
        memberProjects[i] = project;
      }
      that.parallel(memberProjects);
    });
    projects.find({owner : req.session.username}).toArray(function(err, results) {
      if (err) { throw new Error('database problem'); }
      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var project = {
          title : results[i].title,
          id : results[i]._id
        }
        ownerProjects[i] = project;
      }
      that.parallel(ownerProjects);
    });
  },
  function renderTemplate(memberProjects, ownerProjects) {
    res.render('project', {
      ownerProjects : ownerProjects,
      memberProjects : memberProjects
    });
  }
);
```